# How to guess the form of the particular solution in a Non-Homogeneous Linear Recurrence Relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

When determining the form of the particular solution for a recurrence relation is quiet simple, I use the following table:

| $f(n)$ | $a^p_n$ |
| --- | --- |
| c | c |
| $n$ | $cn+d$ |
| $n^2$ | $cn^2+dn+e$ |
| $r^n$ | $cr^n$ |

These generally work for most of my problems but how about when there is a mixture of equations like:

$F(n) = n^22^n$, $F(n) = n^3(-2)^n$, or $F(n) = n2^n$ How can I guess the form of the particular solution in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

I presume these are linear recurrences with constant coefficients.
It's similar to linear constant-coefficient differential equations.
If $f(n) = n^k r^n$ where $k$ is a positive integer, you might try $a_n = p(n) r^n$ where $p(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$.   If $r^n$ is a solution of the homogeneous recurrence relation, the polynomial should have degree $k+1$ but no constant term.  If $n r^n$ is also a solution of the homogeneous recurrence relation, it should have degree $k+2$ but no constant or $n^1$ term.  And so on...

Comment: Or you could convert the recurrence to a differential equation by passing to the exponential generating function, and then use Undetermined Coefficients or Variation of Parameters to find a particular solution for the differential equation.